# Svelte release cycle

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Recently we are doing the update plan for all of our Apps. We have an App using Svelte 3.20.1.
For some projects using Angular it is quite clear to find which Angular versions are supported, so we can plan the date to upgrade the framework beforehand. When we look into Svelte, we cannot find any release cycle info and supported versions of Svelte. I find the latest version of Svelte is 3.37.0 and wondering where I can find this information in regards to the release cycle info and supported versions of Svelte. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Today, there is no TLS version or real roadmap for Svelte.

You can check this issue, but it's probably obsolete : https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/622